# PostgreSQL - Somar valores existentes do Mês actual

Tags: sql, postgresql

Boas pessoal tenho um tabela com coluna data de determinados registos.

Sei que para somar os registos de um determinado dia:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(REPLACE(coluna1,',','.') AS DOUBLE PRECISION)) FROM tabela1 where CAST(data as date)=current_date and xxxxx='111111'
```

Precisava neste momento de uma função que apenas soma-se valores da coluna1 apenas do mês actual..

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode truncar uma data no Postgres com a função [`date_trunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC). De uma maneira simples ela permite que você ignore uma parte da data/hora e se concentre apenas na parte que você quer.

Um exemplo de uso:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', current_date) as este_mes;
        este_mes       
------------------------
 2014-04-01 00:00:00-03
```

Veja que ele truncou a data de hoje e o resultado foi o primeiro dia deste mês porque foi utilizado a palavra-chave `month`, mas você pode truncar na hora, no minuto ou até mesmo no ano. É uma boa alternativa para que você não precise usar a fução `extract` mais de uma vez.

Sendo assim você pode utilizar este recurso para a sua consulta mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT sum(...) as soma 
FROM ... 
WHERE date_trunc('month', data) = date_trunc('month', current_date);
```

Para mais funções de manipulação de data e hora veja http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html.